Why do Bishops and Priests get paid to preach instead of working like everyone else?
I’ve been a follower of Christ for five years now, and as a former Muslim, I’ve learned a lot about the hypocrisy of people and how religion can sometimes be used as a tool for personal gain. There’s a question that’s been on my mind for a long time, and I feel I need to express it.
If these so-called “holy fathers” are truly doing God’s work, why don’t they live and work like everyone else? They’re being paid to preach, so isn’t it essentially just a job for them? It makes me question their sincerity when they’re compensated for what is supposed to be a divine mission.
Take the Pope, for example. Living in a palace, surrounded by servants, and having his hand kissed by common people doesn’t exactly convey a message of humility or authenticity. To me, it feels contradictory to the values they claim to represent.

I think part of the reason is that being an effective minister is so much work that it leaves you with no time for another job. But also, I'm not a Catholic and the opulence of the Papacy is one of my big critiques of Catholicism too...

@CandidMoe, some US pastors do that. Many, many others are just simple church pastors that don't have followings outside of the people that sit in the pews on Sundays.

If you end a statement with a question mark, does it become a real question?

@ABMK Not only is the question clear, but I also elaborated on it by providing further explanation and including an example!

@Matthew Someone is deleting my comments.

Well, at least they are not burning me at the stake.

The current pope takes his meals in the cafeteria along with the other cardinals in the Vatican.  Not exactly a luxury life. And remember the Pope is a head of state and responsible for the entire church. Can you compare him to a secular CEO of a company with over a million employees?

@DJClayworth His role as a spiritual leader demands a higher standard of simplicity and alignment with Gospel teachings than a secular CEO analogy can justify. The Church's wealth and influence, still is in conflict with its moral and spiritual mission, I believe it needs deeper accountability and reform.

Where there are genuine coins worth a bit, there will always be counterfeits.  Where there is something trustworthy, the devil will come along and try and imitate it.  Avoid churches where the ministers offend you with their love of money..sadly there are plenty of them everywhere.  Find the true.  As long as they preach Christ, the only begotten son, crucified for sinners, risen from the dead, as long as there is zeal for him. Avoid wolves in sheep's clothing.

1 Timothy 5:17&18.  Many abuse this but don't throw the baby out with the bath water.

@ElectronSurf Aren't you a follower of Christ? How simple is your lifestyle? Do you own a house? A car? Do you take vacations? Are you following commands not to judge your fellow believers? If all ministers had to earn a living as well as being a church leader wouldn't that mean the gospel was preached less?

@ElectronSurf but who are you to say how the Pope as a spiritual leader should live? Unless you really understand Catholic theology, your comment is speculation at best.

@eques Criticism of the Pope's power isn't about dictating how he should live but questioning the broader implications of centralized authority and its alignment with spiritual values. Understanding Catholic theology is important, but questioning excessive influence and ensuring accountability are universal concerns that transcend specific doctrinal knowledge.

@DJClayworth I don't have any claims such as  priests do, I don't call myself a "father", I'm a sinner.

@ElectronSurf you said " demands a higher standard of simplicity and alignment with Gospel teachings" My point is who are you to say he doesn't. Do you understand the totality of Catholic doctrine?

@ElectronSurf Priests aren't special. Everyone is called to be a follower of Jesus. If you believe that requires a simple lifestyle then I would expect that to be something you do.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Related is St. Thomas Aquinas's defense of mendicant orders' begging: Contra Impugnantes ch. 6 "Is it Lawful for Religious to Live on Alms?"

First, scripture is clear that a priest has the right to make a living through his service. Under the Mosaic Covenant, the entire tribe of Levi was taken to serve God (but only the sons of Aaron were to be priests) and so they were said to have God as their inheritance rather than land like the other tribes. They in turn were to receive portions of things given to God - like sacrifices, offerings, and tithe. The other tribes were also to give the Levis cities of Refuge within each of their territories, but they were dispersed across the nation so that they could dedicate themselves to their service to the Lord. When war came, only the Levis were exempt from battle.
Paul notes this as well (1 Timothy 5:17-18):

The elders who direct the affairs of the church well are worthy of double honor, especially those whose work is preaching and teaching. 18 For Scripture says, “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain,”[a] and “The worker deserves his wages.”

He makes a more detailed defense in 1 Corinthians 9:3-12

This is my defense to those who sit in judgment on me. 4 Don’t we have the right to food and drink? 5 Don’t we have the right to take a believing wife along with us, as do the other apostles and the Lord’s brothers and Cephas[a]? 6 Or is it only I and Barnabas who lack the right to not work for a living? 7 Who serves as a soldier at his own expense? Who plants a vineyard and does not eat its grapes? Who tends a flock and does not drink the milk? 8 Do I say this merely on human authority? Doesn’t the Law say the same thing? 9 For it is written in the Law of Moses: “Do not muzzle an ox while it is treading out the grain.”[b] Is it about oxen that God is concerned? 10 Surely he says this for us, doesn’t he? Yes, this was written for us, because whoever plows and threshes should be able to do so in the hope of sharing in the harvest. 11 If we have sown spiritual seed among you, is it too much if we reap a material harvest from you? 12 If others have this right of support from you, shouldn’t we have it all the more? …

He continues, noting that he has not exercised his rights in this matter so that it not become a hindrance to the gospel - but he never denies this right to others or decries the exercise of it as a bad thing 1 Corinthians 9:12-18

… But we did not use this right. On the contrary, we put up with anything rather than hinder the gospel of Christ. 13 Don’t you know that those who serve in the temple get their food from the temple, and that those who serve at the altar share in what is offered on the altar? 14 In the same way, the Lord has commanded that those who preach the gospel should receive their living from the gospel. 15 But I have not used any of these rights. And I am not writing this in the hope that you will do such things for me, for I would rather die than allow anyone to deprive me of this boast. 16 For when I preach the gospel, I cannot boast, since I am compelled to preach. Woe to me if I do not preach the gospel! 17 If I preach voluntarily, I have a reward; if not voluntarily, I am simply discharging the trust committed to me. 18 What then is my reward? Just this: that in preaching the gospel I may offer it free of charge, and so not make full use of my rights as a preacher of the gospel.

Of course we should be critical of those who are looking to use the gospel to become wealthy. Like those mega churches or the papacy. Obviously many have abused the Gospel for self-gain; and so we must be vigilant and hold our priests and churches to a high standard.
However, we should not treat Paul’s example as a requirement. That would be to undermine the point - he intentionally did not exercise his rights in this matter so that he would have something to boast about. It was a self-sacrifice that went above and beyond what was required of him.
Many miss this point from Paul; what the Law prescribes, what God commands of us, is not optional. It is expected, and thus it is not praiseworthy to do it. When he says things like
Romans 3:28

For we maintain that a person is justified by faith apart from the works of the law.

He is not speaking against works generally, but specifically of the works required by the Mosaic Law. If you don’t murder, you haven’t done anything praiseworthy - that’s just expected. If you don’t work on the Sabbath - good! But that doesn’t merit a reward.
However, if you go above and beyond what the Law prescribes - THEN you are doing something that you can boast about, something that does merit reward. Indeed, this is a strong theme in the NT: we as Christians are called to go above and beyond the Law - and Paul is demonstrating to us what that looks like when he refuses to exercise his right to financial support.

The Mosaic Law provided for the tribe of Levi under specific conditions, within an agrarian society where (they lacked inheritance of land). the Pope’s immense influence and power far exceed what Paul described for spiritual leaders. "we as Christians are called to go above and beyond the Law" I feel like you just have the same question as I do!

@ElectronSurf I am not defending the errors and greed of the papacy. I’m very much not a Catholic. However, it would be erroneous to use Paul’s example of refusing to exercise his rights to an income through his ministry as a criteria / requirement for others. He wasn’t establishing a precedent for what we should demand of our priests - as if it were now Law and the only correct way to run a ministry. To do so would be to completely miss the point of why he did it.

Maybe you could turn this question into a Biblical Basis question because right now it is kind of pointed at hypocrisy in the upper echelons of Catholicism.
I, for one, don't think it's right to consider a Bishop, with the same ecclesial authority, but always under fear for his life, in Africa is living the life of Reilly.  The most cushy curial positions in the Catholic Church always come with the most scrutiny and the highest likelihood that you'll be replaced and left to
Not only that, but the recent Popes have been divesting themselves of particular honors and privileges that may have been what the people wanted for a few hundred years, but seem gauche nowadays. Papal tiaras, etc...
Parish priests in the USA get a stipend. It isn't what one would consider "Bringing home the Bacon" and some live pretty well, but it's only because they're well provided for. Priests in religious orders own practically nothing.
But if I needed to give a Biblical Basis for preaching, rather than working it was like this from the very beginning.

So the Twelve gathered all the disciples together and said, “It would not be right for us to neglect the ministry of the word of God in order to wait on tables.
Acts 6:2

That passage hit me as pretty highfaluting on the part of the apostles, but they weren't punished for it.  It just became the norm.  They need to preach Jesus and be freed from worldly cares to do so.  In my diocese, our Bishop is reorganizing parish life so that for each Parish there are three or four priests and two of them are free to minister to the people, while the other one (who gets the title of Pastor) has to take care of the finances and everything.
It's a good model, I hope, it's also a lived out understanding of the Catholic principle of subsidiarity, which is also Biblical (being how Jethro told Moses to divvy up the people of Israel).  It's also a microchasm for the whole Catholic Church, which is why we have a Pope and Bishops (the successors to the apostles) and Priests (Presbyters) and the officially ordained helpers (the Deacons). All of which is defined pretty clearly throughout the New Testament.

I agree that for those who wish to dedicate themselves fully to their faith, there needs to be a way for them to sustain their livelihood. However, this support should not come from the government, funded by taxpayers, or from external "investments", as these sources can exert undue influence on the religion.

The community or adherents of the faith should ideally provide this support, fostering a self-reliant system that aligns with the spiritual values and principles of the religion itself. The model that you suggested is good indeed.

I have to add that the Pope’s position exemplifies a level of power and influence that goes far beyond what is necessary to sustain a religious leader.

I noticed that you added a "Catholicism" tag to my question, which might make it seem like my question is specifically directed at Catholics. However, my question is universal and not limited to Christianity alone. That said, as a follower of Christ, I prefer to have discussions with those who share my faith. So I'm going to remove that tag.

@ElectronSurf the tag is not a scope it is what you are asking about

I would argue they are paid for work like everyone else. With position of priest and bishop there is a lot of projects to manage, lot of bureaucracy and there is requirement for commitment and dynamics. They have their superior (or are voted into positions) that specifies what should be done. They have to cover for other bishops and priests when necessary.
Just a few anecdotes from my experience:

I recently talked to our local priest. As a local priest he is also responsible for lands owned by church here. This requires a lot of trips to cadastral office for all development nearby.

Local area is bilingual and mass has to be doubled just to keep people satisfied.

Multiple villages falls under our local priest so he has to travel a lot for each mass and funeral.

Local priest used to call bishop for baptism of each 4th child in family, but this become non-manageable with many young families around.

What I would not consider preaching and takes a lot of time are confessions.

Priests and bishops are sometimes reassigned so they have to be free to move at any time. Another local priest spent only year here just to be reassigned again.

Maybe not directly relevant to priests and bishops, but nun in our family was ordered to study university economy degree and then manage finances of assigned institution.



It is a fact that holding an Office in the Catholic Church does not exclude the man from Original Sin, and in rare situations those Traditional Catholic Church office holders have been known to sin, and it is argued that with the Usurpation of Church Vatican and much of our Leadership by anti-Catholic Modernists this has increased much, with Greed being only the start, as we can list the sins were needed when the Vatican persecuted Cardinal Pell for exposing financial wrong-doing in Vatican, leading to his early death after years of suffering.
It is interesting that so many risk Judgment of False-Witness for statements on the personal wealth amassing for Offices in the Catholic Church when most salaries of relatively small and would barely be living-wages if not for the provided support that come with their Office. And so easily found on Web.
.. The Papal salary is 3 coins per year, and he does not even get to keep those, as all his living expenses are covered.
There are men employed by businesses that are given some title yet seem to others not to work at all - yet are charished by the owners as one good idea from them could double or more the value and profits of that business. Those so Blind cannot see value in ideas, or equate work-done as changes in physical situations or activity in physical person.
.. As any programmer or engineer can attest too - that was managed by someone that reacts negatively to finding you staring into space managing complex ideas as objects, to create new algorithms or processes which solves the focused goal, or similar.
The owner and founder of a 35 employee (not counting those in manufacturing) in the Engineering, Manufacturing, and research company I worked for, the owner had the idea that inspired that multimillion-dollar business arriving 'in the shower' .. was he 'working' in that shower?, most would say no.
My Traditional Catholic Priest seems to work 6 days a week with 'on call' Hospital and other duties, and makes a salary a small amount higher than I struggled to live on back in the late 1980's and 1990's.
What percent of your wealth is Salvation worth to you. What if you have millions of dollars? What amount would you thank your Priest or others in Church for that Salvation?
.. with that perspective - are those in the Catholic Church paid too much, and the Ornate Beauty of Her too extensive?
If one soul is saved by the Ornate Beauty of a Church, does that not Testify to the Rightness of it? And if one Satanic Falseness soul-Trap is exposed from the Prudence that was triggered by Ugliness, does that not argue for greater Beauty in all of Truth's Gateways?
I include this with the other rays of sanity and corrections that others have made in comments and the one previous answer already posted.

The point isn't about how much priests or Church leaders earn; it's about the perspective that many see their roles primarily as a means of livelihood rather than a spiritual vocation. Salvation doesn't require intermediaries like priests; the scriptures are accessible for personal study and understanding. While the beauty of churches and their traditions can inspire, it’s worth questioning if such extravagance aligns with the teachings of humility and simplicity found in the very faith they profess to serve.

True faith is personal and direct, without needing excessive material or hierarchical structures to validate it!

@ElectronSurf - As mentioned and stated by St. John as quoted, the complete ministrations of Jesus would require more books then could fit on this world, and those closest to him lived on to share some of those unrecorded ministries in the early Traditional Apostolic Catholic Church, it seems clearly false that scripture alone is all that is needed for Salvation, and the ever deconstruction of Protestant faiths seems to argue of much lacking in this anchorless State of Faith, this argument against Catholicism.

I never claimed that scriptures alone are sufficient for salvation, but rather that the path to salvation is clear, and the resources to follow it are abundant. In the Middle Ages, the Church's refusal to allow the Bible to be translated into vernacular languages, like English, was a deliberate attempt to maintain control over spiritual matters. By restricting access to the scriptures, they positioned themselves as gatekeepers of knowledge and interpretation.

This power dynamic ensured that only the clergy could mediate between the divine and the common people, preserving their authority and influence for their own benefit. Today, however, with the scriptures widely accessible, the path is more transparent than ever, and individuals have the resources to pursue a personal relationship with God without relying solely on intermediaries.

@ElectronSurf you are correct in that I missed the point of no Priests or structural Institution need for Salvation. Although it is against Traditional Catholic Doctrine, in Fear, I might suggest that almost all would be lost in the infinite paths away from God and the Structure and defined path of the True Faith, if followed, keeps us on the narrow road to Salvation, without it all but the small percentage of rare souls will go wrong.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.

I up-voted some of your posts.

As mentioned in other answers; those who dedicate their lives to ministry have a right to be supported by the community. Biblical passages, such as those in 1 Timothy and 1 Corinthians, affirm that those who preach and teach are "worthy of double honor" and that "the worker deserves his wages."
While many priests and ministers live modestly, examples of excess (in wealth, power, or influence) can lead people to question their sincerity and accuse them of hypocrisy. Such lifestyles contradict the values of humility, simplicity, and self-sacrifice that are central to Christ's teachings.
At the heart of this issue is the need for balance. I agree that priests (only those who are fully dedicated) need resources to support themselves. But also they must be examples of the values they teach. Excessive wealth, privileges and hierarchy can damage the trust people have in the church. Moreover, the income of priests should not open the door for outside (governments, institutions or individuals) influences to sway their decisions or actions.
Priests who use their resources to serve others, build community, and live according to Christ's teachings can strengthen the credibility of their ministry.
Christians must stay vigilant, holding their spiritual leaders accountable and ensuring their focus remains on the transformative message of faith, not personal gain.
Salvation does not come from the church, priests, or the pope. Christ is the salvation.

To those who judge these leaders, who know not their lives... I humbly point out Matthew 7:1-2. We do not know what is going on, we usually jump to a unfair conclusion. (This is of course very difficult to do with the more ... gospel of wealth tv preachers... )

@Wyrsa Accountability is not the same as judgment. Questioning behavior that appears inconsistent with their calling is not unfair but a necessary part of maintaining integrity and trust within our community.

I do not disagree, I just point out that we should be wary of our own situation and careful about how we do it if we choose to do so.


OP: If these so-called “holy fathers” are truly doing God’s work, why don’t they live and work like everyone else?

We see the Pope, Patriarch, and Pastors who do have wealth, but there are other servants we don't always see who do live like most believers.
In either case, they believe they are spreading the Gospel, doing God's work.  In fact, many do come to Christ because of their opulent or humble work.

Judge not according to the appearance, but judge righteous judgment. John 7:24

To be fair, there are some who preach a false gospel, yet, God can use them for His Glory.

Some indeed preach Christ even of envy and strife; and some also of good will: The one preach Christ of contention, not sincerely, supposing to add affliction to my bonds: But the other of love, knowing that I am set for the defence of the gospel. What then? notwithstanding, every way, whether in pretence, or in truth, Christ is preached; and I therein do rejoice, yea, and will rejoice. Philippians 1:15-18

Either way, whether in pretense or truth, Christ is preached and thus we rejoice.

The argument that God uses both opulent and humble works might unintentionally validate the prosperity gospel. a teaching that equates material wealth with divine favor. This ideology can distort Christian doctrine, focusing on personal gain rather than self-sacrifice and service. Paul warned against those who "suppose that godliness is a means of gain" (1 Timothy 6:5-10).

Also Jesus himself lived humbly while having divine authority, his sacrifices should be a model to those following his path. take up your cross and follow me not "hop on your limousine"!

John 7:24 advises against judgment by the appearance, sure. righteous judgment requires careful understanding of actions and intentions. A "father's" lifestyle can provide insights into their priorities and alignment with Jesus.

It’s true that the message of Christ can be powerful regardless of the messenger's intent or lifestyle, the behavior of those in leadership influences how the Gospel is perceived. The Apostle Paul often emphasized his own sacrifice and humility to ensure his ministry was above reproach (2 Corinthians 11:7-9).

Most pastors I know are less well paid than most of their church members. They are absolutely certainly paid less well than a secular manager with a similar sized staff and budget.

@DJClayworth It's not about how much their salary is, you're missing the point.

@ElectronSurf my view is that the "prosperity gospel" or "name it and claim it" has pretty much self-corrected.  It is important to note your seeing the difference between the gospel and certain people who preach the gospel.  Don't let it undermine your faith.

@SLM Seeing their hypocrisy has no impact on my faith, I know them well... but it deeply bothers me to see them misleading and disappointing people who genuinely love Jesus. As brothers and sisters in faith, how did we allow this to happen. letting evil desires and individuals with ulterior motives infiltrate and overcome the Church?

While I see the question is directed loosely at Catholics, there is a broad understanding here that a priest needs the time to fulfill his duties within the framework of the religion. (regardless of which religion)
I will answer from the Eastern Orthodox perspective, cause we have a similar situation. It would be ethically and morally questionable from a secular worldly perspective to not pay a priest. If only because the priest has made a commitment that is lifelong through the sacrament of ordination, you commit to your calling forever unless you get excommunicated for something like heresy or criminal activity)
I've seen very very elderly priests, (almost always with a younger priest) in some churches. They seem to never retire, they just have less responsibility but remain within the church.

Official church position: Priests should be paid fairly.
From the OCA website (The Orthodox Church of America) this is also a question as well. (Though it is framed to focus on married priests not getting paid enough, the core question is the same)

For many, many years, the OCA has had a clergy compensation guideline in place. In short, it asks that parishes pay their priests at the same rate that a professional of his particular stature, education, and experience would receive in their respective communities. It also requests parishes to give their priests annual raises as well as cost-of-living increases based on the Consumer Price Index. Further, virtually every diocese of the Orthodox Church in America has compensation guidelines which compliment those issued by the Central Church Administration.
It is only my opinion, but the problem does not necessarily lie with the hierarchs, the Central Church Administration, or the dioceses. They have done a stellar job in promoting fair and adequate compensation of our clergy. The problem is that many parishes choose not to comply, for a variety of reasons, some valid, others ridiculous.

So people are concerned that a priest who serves "2 masters" will be unable to fulfill their spiritual role as a leader of the church. (An orthodox church has so many things that the priest has to do, a second job would significantly reduce the priests available time)

A newly-assigned priest that has just graduated from the Seminary should make an annual salary of $49,128-$66,528 plus extra benefits such as insurance, an automobile, a house (or an allowance for one) retirement contributions, seminars expenses, among other ones. A priest with 35 years of ministry and more will earn $113,856-$120,144, according to the Clergy Compensation Plan for 2013.
The priests’ salaries are the biggest expense of the parishes’ annual budgets, along with the annual monetary allocation they pay to the Archdiocese for what are called ministries.
According to the official Clergy Compensation Plan for 2013, a priest with service of up to five years can expect to earn $49,128-$66,528; 6-10 years $68,528-$74,136; 11-15 years $74,136-84,960; 16-20 years $84,960-$94,440; 21-25 years $94,440-$101,136; 26-30 years $101,136-$107,616; 31-35 years $107,616-$113,856; and over 35 years $113,856-$120,144.
Written by Theodore Kalmoukos in 2013

So we see that the official orthodox church position is that priests should be paid. And indirectly we see that some average priests are underpaid. We also see that the Church attempts to be fair and reasonable about it. If the church has housing for the priest, they get paid less, if the church provides a car, etc. as well as fulfilling all the government requirements.
however...

Results may vary!

The above salary scale is not always observed by the local Metropolises. In many parishes there are huge differences of salaries and benefits. Some Metropolitans in order to take care “their own boys” as the expression goes, put pressure on the parishes to give them more money, in some instances even double the amount that the Archdiocesan salary scale directs. Generally in Metropolises, it is the metropolitan, not the chancellor, that selects a priest. In many cases, the unwritten laws of friendship and favoritism prevail over education, experience, and overall ability.
In other instances, the metropolitans turn their heads the other way. TNH has learned that there are priests with 50-plus years of continuous service in the same parish whose annual salary does not exceed $50,000, while some newly-appointed priests begin at $80,000. The priest in the Archdiocesan Cathedral of the Holy Trinity in New York, appointed by Archbishop Demetrios, earns the highest salary of any priest in the country, plus benefits, while other clergy live below poverty line.
Written by Theodore Kalmoukos in 2013

Now admittedly this information is 10 years out of date, and I would argue that the priest within new york city (which is a rather expensive place to live) should likely get more. But perhaps not that much more... so things appear unbalanced and worldly. And I say to this that it is. The Church tries to be fair, but it swings in both directions, for various reasons. However the reason shouldn't be "for luxury"

Real life tends to affect things, aka the earth gets in the way of the spiritual.
It is not uncommon for an orthodox priest to have a 2nd job. It is actually a rather sad reality to know that they sometimes must. This other job could be a very high paying one, you cannot know from looking. But it is also true that a priest could come from a wealthy family, or be married to someone who has a high paying job. (Although... the priest's wife is supposed to be very busy as well)
So it is not often, but it does stick out more, when the priest has a luxury car or something. I think the issue here is perspective, why are you judging the priest negatively? If you are concerned with a specific priest, you should talk to them... if you feel bad after talking to them about it, be open about it.

Gifts are usually "high quality"
Consider the monks/priests on Mt. Athos use whatever car is donated to them. And generally people do not donate "cheap shit" to the church. Similar to offerings in the old testament people want to give something good. So monks on Mt. Athos might drive a medium-high end BMW while I use public transit. I do not begrudge them this. (Or that the most reclusive monks on Athos might get luxury black tea)

Priests are expected to behave appropriately.
Regardless of what your skills are, when you become a priest are expected to behave like one. That does not mean you should abandon your skills. Why am I even bringing this up? Well... there are Orthodox Priests who come from the financial sector. He handles serious amounts of money, like 20 million. It is all about what he does with the money that matters. (He has a podcast, and is highly active trying to do good things)
Is there any basis for paying a priest at all though?
Of course! Even the old testament points to the levite priests getting paid. The Tithe was collected from the other tribes so that the levites could be dedicated to only working for the Lord. They actually were required to tithe three different things.
First, Jews were required to tithe to support the Levite priests (Numbers 18:21-24). Since the priests were devoted entirely to serving the Lord in the temple, tithes were collected from the other tribes to support the priests. (This included the Levites!)
Secondly, the Jews were required to give an additional tithe to support the three festivals of Passover, Pentecost, and Tabernacles (Deuteronomy 12; 14:22-26). The tithes of the Jewish community funded these three key festivals.
Finally, Jews were instructed to give another tithe every third year for the poor (Deuteronomy 14:28-29). Taken together, all three tithes totaled between twenty to thirty percent of a Jew's income, depending on the year.
The entire lives of the Levites was an offering. God was the focus of their service, the source of their sustenance, and the significance of their calling. After the conquest of Canaan, the Levites, given the fact that they were to "have no allotment in their land," nor "any share," lived in scattered areas, usually near one of the forty-eight specially designated cities (Numbers 35:6). (See also Deuteronomy 18:1-2 "The Lord is their inheritance")

Living by example... Our Ecumenical Patriarch.
While there is no openly disclosed documents on how much the Patriarch earns, He has no scandals. He might have a comfortable vehicle provided by the church, and he does live in a historic home dedicated for housing the Ecumenical Patriarch... he wears modest, albeit high quality, clergy attire when not formally performing his duties.
His All-Holiness Bartholomew I. The Ecumenical Patriarchate of Constantinople has no notable financial scandals. Nor have the previous 5 Patriarchs.
I do not claim that we have no financial corruption, priests are human and sin. But we do our best to be responsible with the gifts God gives us to care for the church and mankind.

Priests should receive minimal wages sufficient to cover their basic needs and responsibilities, aligning with their vocation of humility and service. This ensures they can dedicate themselves fully to their spiritual duties without the distractions of financial insecurity, while also avoiding the perception of materialism or luxury that might alienate their communities.

A priest’s role is spiritual, not about earning money like regular jobs. Comparing them to others in society takes away from their purpose of serving God with humility and sacrifice.

@ElectronSurf The first issue you raise, is addressed. The guidelines within the Orthodox Church are that they receive a wage similar to a professional. This allows them to "not walk too fast, nor walk too slow" so that they do not draw unwanted/incorrect attention. (St Ambrose/Chrysostom). I agree though, they should not receive excessive salaries, or if they do a respectable priest would likely use the extra income for the church.

@ElectronSurf the 2nd issue, becoming a priest within the Orthodox church in attempt to become wealthy or gain power is objectively doomed from the get go. If one wanted to do that, I would suggest becoming a con artist of the church of wealth, "god" says I need a new jet, and if you buy just 100 Jesus Token you can get yo mommy saved. My wallet address is....
